# Unable to run simple lift web example

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

When I attempt to convert to JSON string from List I receive the compile-time error:

```
'JsonAST.RenderSettings.compact.type' does not take parameters
```

src:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._

implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

val json = ("name" -> "joe")

compact(render(json))
```

Excluding the imports, the above code is copied from https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json

Here is the `build.sbt` entry:

```
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.4.1",
```

How to further debug what my issue is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not so updated. With liftweb 3.1.0 this has moved from `pretty(render())` to `prettyRender()`. [Here](https://github.com/lift/framework/commit/7dbf96fa348e799b335e555ba44204af4a723400) is the commit that did it. You can also do `compactRender()`. Both are part of `net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._` You should do:

```
val json = ("name" -> "joe")
println(compactRender(json))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ttbG0pJzQy2ks9HLpFh7Dw).